# How to use multiple IDs in one function

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to use it on multiple ids such that when #more1 is clicked , #details1 will appear. And when #more2 is clicked , #details2 will appear?
Note that I want it only using one function.
Thank U.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#more1,#more2').click(function () {
        $('#details1,#details2').slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: For repeatability, I recommend using classes instead of IDs. It might help to include your HTML and a [working demonstration](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a more general selector: `$('[id^="more"]')`.
This will select all items that have an `id` that starts with "more", and will have a click event tied to them.

Then you can use the number in the `id` property and use it to build the `id` of the target.

```js
$('[id^="more"]').click(function()
{
    let id = $(this).attr('id');
    let num = /\d+/.exec(id)[0];
    $('#details' + num).slideToggle();                  
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('[id^="more"]').click(function()
    {
        let id = $(this).attr('id');
        let num = /\d+/.exec(id)[0];
        $('#details' + num).slideToggle();                  
    });    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <button id="more1">One</button>
  <span id="details1">Each Section</span>
</div>
<div>
  <button id="more2">Two</button>
  <span id="details2">Is Independent</span>
</div>
<div>...</div>
<div>
  <button id="more25">Twenty Five</button>
  <span id="details25">Of all the others</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the `id` of the current item and act accordingly:

```
if($(this).attr('id') == 'more1') $('#details1').slideToggle();
```

A more elegant solution would be:

```
$('#details' + $(this).attr('id')[$(this).attr('id').length - 1]).slideToggle();
```

The last one uses the fact that the numbering in the ids is similar, and if you have less than 10 such ids it will work properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use for loop

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var length = 9; // any number you need
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {

        $('#more' + i).click(function()
        {
           $('#details' + i).slideToggle();                  
        });    
    }
                              
});
```